# Explain this error in Scala (type parameters)

Tags: scala, types

While experimenting with type variables, I tried following code and it failed (attempted to write a generic code which could add any two data types).

What surprised me was the error. Why does the compiler complain that it expects a String data type? I didn't mention String anywhere in the code

```
scala> def add[A](x:A, y:A) = {x+y}
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A
 required: String
       def add[A](x:A, y:A) = {x+y
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `A` isn't bounded by anything, it could be any type. Specifically, that type doesn't necessarily have a `+` method (which you try to invoke in the method body). Then, compiler tries to find some *implicit conversion* that might turn `x` into some type with a `+` method, and it finds [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.Predef$$any2stringadd) implicit conversion into `String` from `Predef.scala`:

```
implicit final class any2stringadd[A](private val self: A) extends AnyVal {
  def +(other: String): String = String.valueOf(self) + other
}
```

So, the method body becomes equivalent to:

```
String.valueOf(x).+(y)
```

But then - compiler fails because `String.+` expects a String argument, and `y` isn't a String.

**EDIT**:
To create a "generic" addition function, you must bound your type `A` in a way that ensures it can be added. One way of doing that is using the `Numeric` type:

```
def add[A : Numeric](x:A, y:A) = { implicitly[Numeric[A]].plus(x, y) }
```

which means your function can be called for any type `A` for which an implicit `Numeric[A]` exists.

Comment: Excellent explanation!!